# Filtering data using Pandas .loc function

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, pandas-loc

I have a df of car miles per gallon data, which are int (as far as I can tell).

Using Pandas, I'm filtering with `df.loc[(df['Horsepower'] >90)]` which is giving me the results I expect - cars with >90 horsepower. But when I try adding a second filter, I get the below error.

```
>> df.loc[(df['Horsepower'] >90)] & (df['Weight']< 4500)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'
```

Is it a syntax issue or am i missing something bigger??

Answer (score 3):

You have got typo in your code. The brancket `]` has to be at the end of the filter:

```
df.loc[(df['Horsepower'] >90) & (df['Weight']< 4500)]
```